# Calculus simple question, who is right?

Tags: calculus

I have the following budget constrain: $p_1\cdot P+p_2\cdot C=100$ and I also have this equality that I have to plug into the budget constrain: $2P=C$

So: $p_1\cdot P+p_2\cdot 2P=100$ , so now I want to isolate $P$, what I do is as follows: $p_1\cdot P+P=\frac{100}{2\,p_2}$

then $P+P= (\frac{100}{2\,p_2}+p_1)$ so what I have is $2P= (\frac{100}{2\,p_2}+p_1)$

The book gives as a solution $P=\frac{100}{2p_2+p_1}$... why is that? I keep checking and going over the equation and I a still getting $2P$ in one side of it... is the book wrong? or I am making a silly mistake?

Cheers!

Comment: does $p1$ mean $p_1$ etc?. It would be helpful if you wrote your equations in $\TeX$ code

Comment: yes it does, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake lies in that
$$
p_1 P+p_2 2P=100 \tag{1}
$$
is *not* equivalent to
$$
p_1 P+P=\frac{100}{2p_2}.
$$
You're forgetting to divide the first term $p_1P$ with $2p_2$ as well. Instead, notice that $P$ is a common factor of the left-hand expression and hence $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$
P(p_1+2p_2)=100
$$
which yield the result from your book.

Answer (score 3):

You have $$p_1 P+p_2\times 2P=100$$ then you arrange
$$p_1 P+2p_2P=100$$
and note that $P$ is a common factor: so we factor
$$P(p_1 +2p_2)=100$$
now we can divide by $(p_1 +2p_2)$ to find
$$P=\frac{100}{p_1 +2p_2}$$